# Using LINQ with express version of visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to use LINQ in the express version of visual studio? I am planning on refactoring my project to use LINQ, but I am the only person in my group that has a copy of visual studio pro. Will that cause any problems if someone using the express version has to modified my code?

**Edit**
I realize that the graphical tools are not available in the express version, so my question does not pertain to those. I am more interested in the actual code, which I assume will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

From the [Visual C# Express 2008 page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/):

> Build applications using LINQ (Language Integrated Query) which adds data querying capabilities for SQL Server, XML, and objects to Visual C#

Comment: Hmm, thats for C#, although I assume that it will work for vb aswell

Answer (score 0):

I found the same information on the VB Express 2008 page

http://www.microsoft.com/express/vb/Default.aspx

> Build applications using LINQ (Language Integrated Query) which adds data querying     capabilities for SQL Server, XML, and objects to Visual Basic